# How to delete and object from an array

Tags: javascript

How can I delete an object from an array.?

I have created an `array` and each element of this array contain one `object`. Also, the array has been associated to a HTML `table`. How can I create a function where if I click on a delete button in one `row` of the `table` it will delete that specific `row` but also delete that specific `object` in the `array`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two removers one that will remove the `tr` element from the `table` and another that will remove the `object` from the `array`. You could find the element from the target using  the clicked element and then remove it from its parent node using `removeChild`. Finally, you could use `splice` to remove the object from the array.

Please check this implementation.

```js
var array = [];
var rowButtons = document.querySelectorAll('td > div');
rowButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  var object = {
    id: button.id.split('_')[1],
    name: button.id
  };
  array.push(object);
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var index = this.id.split('_')[1];
    console.log(index);
    if (index > -1) {
      var trNode = this.parentNode.parentNode;
      if (trNode.nodeName && trNode.nodeName === 'TR') {
        trNode.parentNode.removeChild(trNode); // remove from table
      }
      array.splice(index, 1); //remove from array
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-color: #aabcfe;
  }
  
  .tg td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: #aabcfe;
    color: #669;
    background-color: #e8edff;
  }
  
  .tg th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: #aabcfe;
    color: #039;
    background-color: #b9c9fe;
  }
  
  .tg .tg-jb4r {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-n1xd {
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #333333;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-yjn3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-ggmw {
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-kybs {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top
  }
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-jb4r">No</td>
      <th class="tg-jb4r">Competition</td>
        <th class="tg-jb4r">John</td>
          <th class="tg-jb4r">Adam</td>
            <th class="tg-jb4r">Robert</td>
              <th class="tg-jb4r">Paul</td>
                <th class="tg-jb4r">Action</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-n1xd">1</td>
    <td class="tg-n1xd">Swimming</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">1:30</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">2:05</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">1:15</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">1:41</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">
      <div id="tr_0">Delete</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yjn3">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yjn3">Running</td>
    <td class="tg-kybs">15:30</td>
    <td class="tg-kybs">14:10</td>
    <td class="tg-kybs">15:45</td>
    <td class="tg-kybs">16:00</td>
    <td class="tg-kybs">
      <div id="tr_1">Delete</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-n1xd">3</td>
    <td class="tg-n1xd">Shooting</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">70%</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">55%</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">90%</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">88%</td>
    <td class="tg-ggmw">
      <div id="tr_2">Delete</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an item from an array. You could then hide the element in the table or get that element from the `target` per the button or click. Finally, you could make a DELETE request to the backend if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Use splice

```
 $.each(someArray, function(i){
        if(someArray[i].name === 'Sample') {
            someArray.splice(i,1);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

or use JQuery.grep

```
someArray = jQuery.grep(someArray , function (value) {
        return value.name != 'Sample';
});
```

or filter

```
var filtered = someArray.filter(function(el) { return el.Name != "Sample"; });
```

Comment: Except that splicing while looping cause problems.